# Streaming with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, streaming

I want to stream real-time data from a server into a JavaScript webpage. For example, if the server receives meteorological data measurements every second, I want to visualize them as a moving graph on the webpage.

Naturally, Ajax can be used for this. However, this is not what the HTTP protocol was built for. It would help to have a faster, more lightweight protocol. Ideally, a persistent TCP connection. Are there any such possibilites in modern browsers, without using additional plugins and applets? Or can this be only done with Flash, Java, etc...?

Comment: Check WebSockets but its main problem still remains cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/). It tries to make use of [WebSockets](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/), but can fall back on standard AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers support the Websocket implementation, however as David says, in case your browser does not support it, it will fall back to Flash sockets, Ajax, iframe long polling etc. It's a high level wrapper and easy to implement. Server side you will use nodejs and socket.io, check the documentation of socket.io